# Ubuntu 16.04 stuck on shutdown/reboot with "recovering journal" line

Tags: 16.04, uefi, ssd, shutdown, reboot

**My Problem:**

Ubuntu doesn't shutdown/reboot and is stuck on line like:

`/dev/sda: clean, xxx/xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks`

and sometimes with several similiar lines and sometimes with

`recovering journal`

at the top.

At first the problem was that it stucked with

`CPU#X stucked for XXs`

but I've managed it somehow from the list below :)

**What's done:**

1. sudo update && upgrade && dist-upgrade` and loaded updates with ubuntu-software-center.
2. `sudo purge nvidia*` and `sudo apt-get install nvidia-361`
3. switched to Intel HD card in "Nvidia settings" (nvidia prime).
4. fixed grub with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force`
5. (tried `apm=power_off` and `acpi=noirq` too).(tried `apm=power_off` and `acpi=noirq` too).
6. disabled `usb 3.0 legacy mode`.
7. disabled swap partition with `sudo swapoff /dev/sdaX` and commented it's entry in fstab.
8. smth in `/etc/modules` I've forgotten..

**My hardware:**

MSI GE62 6QD (Laptop);
i5 6300HQ (4 cores);
intel hd530 + Nvidia gtx 960;
16gb RAM DDR4;
Windows 10 UEFI on default 1TB HDD;
SSD Intel 540s via M.2 (UBUNTU UEFI);
Dualboot via bootmenu (F11) yet..

I just didn't update kernel manually, but I can try if you'll help me a little with right way of doing it.

Installation process didn't go easy too. It got stucked on first "preparing" screen with "Ubuntu" logo. Solved with `nomodeset` in boot params.
I've tried hackintosh OSX El Capitan on this M.2 SSD and it worked rather fine (of course not excellent).

I'm very sorry, cause I'm not a guru in kernels/terminal/bootargs/etc, so I tried almost every solution that helped somebody..

Hope for your help. I need my lovely OS working well on my new monster-laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed with this issue, but still have some little problem.
I edited `/etc/default/grub` added `pci=nomsi` param to bootparams line like that: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nomsi"` and laptop now reboots and loads fine, BUT only if 'Nvidia card' enabled in 'Nvidia settings'. If I switch it to 'IntelHD' (IntelHD530 in my case) laptop still stucks on shutdown and goes to login loop if I try to relogin. It doesn't rather disturb me but IntelHD provides more smooth interface performance and less battery consumption than Nvidia card does :( What have I do? Are the latest nvidia drivers provide smoothness or not? Or maybe there's more simple solution to make IntelHD working fine too?

Comment: Did you figure this out? Either way, you should post this as a separate question (linking back to this one)—if you figured it out, answer your own question; if not, other people will see it and might be able to answer it. Asking a question inside an answer won't get you the attention/help you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on a Dell XPS 15 2017 (GTX-1050 GPU).
Eventually, the solution that fixed everything for me is the following (at least for my system configuration):

- edit **/etc/default/grub**
- add `acpi_rev_override=1` to your GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT parameters

(in my case the following line looks like this):

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_rev_override=1"

- run `update-grub` from the terminal

after shutting down your machine one more time from the power button, the problem should have been fixed.
then you can install the latest nvidia drivers (384 work fine for me) along with the default ones for the intel GPU.

Answer (score 0):

My laptop is also GE62 with a 970m graphic cards. At first my problem was that the 'recovering journal' shows up during the shutdown process. After trying all possible solutions I can find online, such as the solution suggested above, the problem changed and my screen freezes after pressing restart or shutdown button.

And the suggestion to install Nvidia in this thread, which is also one of your steps, solves my last problem: [Installation of Ubuntu 16.04 from a USB drive freezes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861743/installation-of-ubuntu-16-04-from-a-usb-drive-freezes)

"

The solution to both of these was to install nvidia. Type in terminal:

> sudo apt-get install nvidia

Press tab twice and see which nvidia is the newest. For example, it will look like:

> sudo apt-get install nvidia-352

Hopefully it will be the same for you.

"

And I believe this is not only the problem with GE62, other laptops which are equipped with Nvidia credit cards (especially gaming laptops) may have the similar issues during the installation or after installation.