# ASUS ROG GL752VW Ubuntu installation issues

Tags: asus

I use ASUS ROG GL752VW laptop with 960M series Nvidia Geforce graphics card. I tried both nomodeset and nouveau.modeset=0 to install Ubuntu 16.04 but it shows GRUB error in the last part of installing Ubuntu. How can i install Ubuntu 16.04 perfectly in my laptop?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

having the same laptop model, this worked for me:

[Installation of Ubuntu 16.04 from a USB drive freezes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861743/installation-of-ubuntu-16-04-from-a-usb-drive-freezes)

try adding either "acpi=off" or "acpi=force" in the GRUB menu then you should be able to boot from the live USB

Answer (score 0):

I have the same notebook and I couldn't for the life of me install Ubuntu as a second OS alongside Windows.

So what I did is:

- disable Secure Boot in BIOS
- boot the USB drive in UEFI
- install Ubuntu 18.04 with Erase Disk option
- re-enable Secure Boot in BIOS (I did this because I used to receive and error along the lines of "UEFI db could not be loaded/found" and this solved it)
- at this point I still had major problems with booting into Ubuntu, but at least I could get to the GRUB loader so I booted Ubuntu in Recovery Mode
- I used a terminal to modify the GRUB and I set acpi=off

After that last step it worked like a charm.

Another piece of information I can give you regarding that installation error about grub (something about grub-efi-amd64) is that one way to solve this is by creating another partition of ~500-1000 mb as an EFI Filesystem Partition as per this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMCfS8CDW0c&t=321s

I have to warn you though, this completely messed up my computer. After doing this I couldn't get any OS to boot and got an error message similar to "Please restart and choose a proper boot media...".

PS: I am a complete newbie to Ubuntu/Linux, I've just thrown my two cents in the hopes that it could help.