# "Couldn't get UEFI db list " bug after the second opening Ubuntu

Tags: uefi, acpi

I am trying to migrate Wİndows to Ubuntu.I have prepared bootable USB with rufus. I restarted my laptop and went to the setup page, setting my USB drive as main boot option and disabling all other options.

I encountered the same following problem:
[Installation of Ubuntu 16.04 from a USB drive freezes](https://askubuntu.com/q/861743/861776)
I fixed this problem with using acpi=off.

I have erased all disk and made clean installation.On the first opening I have installed development tools(JDK,Netbeans...) and move my files to Ubuntu.On the second opening I get following GRUB menu.

```
1.Advanced GRUB Options for Ubuntu
2.Ubuntu
```

After choosing the second option , I get following error.

```
ACPI Error : [_UPC] Namespace lookup failure,AE_ALREADYEXIST(Z0170031/dswload-378)

ACPI Exception : AE_ALREADY_EXIST During name lookup/catalog failure

ACPI Exception : AE_ALREADY_EXIST(SSDT:xh_rupli) while loading table (Z0170831/tbxfload-228)

ACPI Error : 1 table load failures, 0 successful(Z0170831/tbxfload-228)
Couldn't get size : 0x800000000...e
MODSIGN :Couldn't get UEFI db list
```

I have done some research on internet find following solutions:

**First Solution**
I closed Secure Boot from BIOS settings but It didn't work.I still get same error.

*Ubuntu version : 18.04.1 LTS*

Comment: Try to make boot USB with **etcher** program https://www.balena.io/etcher/ I've got the same problem, but after use **etcher**, I've successful result!

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. I almost forget that question. I have fixed this problem by using nomodeset instead of acpi=off.I have no idea what I have done should I answer my question?

Comment: Yes you should answer your own question, and accept it (maybe after a 3 day delay, but not sure if the delay is still applicable at this point).