# Hard disk not detected

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, permissions, mount

I have recently purchased an HP Omen 15t laptop, and I want to dual boot it. I made a pen drive with ubuntu in it (GPT scheme), disable fastboot and I tried to install it. But the screen was getting frozen, so according to an answer on this site, I pressed e while booting, and then added `acpi = off` after `quiet splash` line. [The answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861743/installation-of-ubuntu-16-04-from-a-usb-drive-freezes) I don't know whether this is relevant.

Now the freezing issue is solved, but my hard disk is not being read by the installer. It says that I only have 8.2GB of space. Which is definitely my pen drive. I have created 40GB portion using disk partition utility which should register as free space. When I run `fdisk -l`, it shows this:

```
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop0: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop1: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop2: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop3: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop4: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop5: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop6: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop7: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Permission denied
```

What do I do now?

EDIT:
I ran the same command as sudo, so now permission is not denied, but it only shows the partitions and space in the pen drive. It does not show the 40 GB section that I have free.

Comment: run that like this `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: But that will not solve the problem for the installer, right? It is stopping saying that I don't have space for my installation.

Comment: Okay, actually it does help. It does not show my hard disk. It only shows the pen drive. So I know for sure that the HDD is not getting detected.