# Will the "discrete graphics card" BIOS setting on HP ZBOOK G3 allow me to switch between graphics cards?

Tags: graphics, bios

I have a HP zbook G3 laptop. When installing Ubuntu, the BIOS settings are as nicely described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1040121/527764).

For the graphics card there are three settings:

1. discrete graphics card
2. enable hybrid graphics
3. Auto.

In the post I referred to, setting 1 is used. Is it possible to switch between dedicated and internal graphic cards with this BIOS setting?

Comment: It looks like 2 and 3 should work for manual switching. You could text to find out, or use the default settings. For more info, I'd consult the zbook's manual.

Comment: Thanks! I also edited my question and referred to another thread. Hope to get some more insight by this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. To be able to install Ubuntu at all on HP zbook G3 laptop, follow the referred post above. In this post the discrete graphics setting (setting 1) needs to be chosen in the BIOS. As far as I know, this setting does NOT allow to switch between two different graphic cards. Running the command

`lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"`, 
does only show my Quadro dedicated graphics card, not the Intel integrated graphics card.

However, AFTER the Ubuntu installation, you can change back to hybrid graphics in BIOS (setting 2). I have not tested setting 3: Auto in BIOS. Using setting 2 in BIOS allow us to switch between the dedicated graphics card and internal graphics card as described here:

https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-card-ubuntu

By running `lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"`, now both my graphics card are shown in the output.