# Ubuntu installation freezes at loading screen

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install ubuntu 18.04.04 and I get stuck on the loading screen as shown in the pic. How should I resolve this issue?

PS

i. fast boot and security boot are disabled.

ii. TRX 40 motherboard, CPU: TR 3970X

[Ubuntu installation freezes at loading screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4YUy.jpg)

Comment: Please add alteast some basic information like OS/Version, etc.

Comment: Unplug ALL USB devices and see if it boots.

Answer (score 0):

You could be facing a graphics driver problem. Possibly the Ubuntu version you're installing expects something like OpenGL 3, but your card doesn't support it.

Try the key combination ALT+CONTROL+F5 (or some other function key) to open a terminal and login with a root account. Then run tools like DMESG to inspect where the problem arises. Maybe you need to follow the procedure to get into recoverymode first. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Perhaps this article can help: [Installation of Ubuntu 16.04 from a USB drive freezes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861743/installation-of-ubuntu-16-04-from-a-usb-drive-freezes)

Comment: Hi Pianoman, I could not enter the stage where the ubuntu logo shows.

I think the linux kernel is not correctly loaded so I cannot use the terminal neither. 

Thanks!