# Ubuntu 18.04's installation/boot freezes

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, usb

### Story

A year ago, I got a new laptop `ASUS TUF Gaming FX505`, Windows 10 wasn't really easy to use so I switched so I decided to install `Ubuntu 18.04` on it with a **USB Key** alongside of Windows 10. I had some various issues because the BIOS is not well suited for that kind of application, but **it worked fine at the time**.

This week, I ran into major issues and **needed to re-install** `Ubuntu 18.04` because **I'm not able to boot**, (anyway, I was planning to re-install it because I had some issues) but now, the USB Key I used to install Ubuntu doesn't work anymore!

### Issue

When **trying to boot** from the USB Key, it gives a terminal-like screen with four option, 
`Try Ubuntu`, `Install Ubuntu` *and some others options I don't remember*.
When I select one of thoses two options, it tries to boot from the USB Key, at this point, it either freezes like that:
[image: MisterUbuntuFreeze]
Or if I selected the `Try Ubuntu` option, **I get a frozen desktop**, but the mouse is free.
Or if I selected the `Install Ubuntu` option, **I get a frozen desktop again** but with the download Ubuntu **dialog box, empty**, there is just the **language selection visible**, oh and **everything is frozen** of course! But the mouse is free.

Now, to shut-off Ubuntu, it also doesn't work! **I'm forced to do a long push** on the power button to turn off Ubuntu.

So, I can't run any command in the Terminal.

Remember that **it worked a year ago** but not now!

### What I tried to do

• I downloaded a **new** `.iso` of Ubuntu 18.04 and used Startup Disk Creator (on another PC) **on the USB Key that used to work**.
Unfortunately, it didn't worked.
• Then I did it **on a better USB Key**.
And got the same issue.
• Eventually, I **tried on another computer, and it was working**, there was no issues like that.
I guess which my computer doesn't like Ubuntu...
• I looked on Internet and found some solutions, but some needed to press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key but when I do that, **it does absolutely nothing**, and pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> just switches between the boot screen or the boot terminal where **I can't input any command**. **So no solution found on any other posts.**
• I tried to boot with `nomodeset` but **I can't even get the Live session.**

### Computer Specs

ASUS TUF Gaming FX505, laptop including:

- An Intel Core i7 8750H CPU (6 cores for 12 threads at 2200MHz)
- A NVIDIA GeForce GTX 10-Series GPU
- 8GiB of memory
- A 1TB HDD on and a 256GB SSD

*Credits:
The image above was took from this post: [Installation of Ubuntu 16.04 from a USB drive freezes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861743/installation-of-ubuntu-16-04-from-a-usb-drive-freezes).*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Boot with `nomodeset`.

Comment: My computer doesn't boot on a black screen but, I'll try that post.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Check the NVIDIA related answers in the called duplicate question. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I found that `Kubuntu 14` on another USB key worked.*
I then downloaded the **newest** `iso` of Ubuntu being `Ubuntu 20.04`.
I then used Startup Disk Creator on an USB key laying around with another computer.

Then, with the USB key with `Ubuntu 20.04`, **it worked**!
I'm unsure of what happened. **I guess** there could have been some **corruptions** on the downloaded `iso`.

*Also, for some computers, the issue could be that the CPU is a 32-Bit one, so it's better to check that before, and take the right OS for it.*