# Ubuntu 18 LTS & 20 LTS freeze on boot from USB

Tags: boot, 18.04, 20.04, usb

I'm in the process of repurposing an old-to-me PC into a home server. I've been trying to install Ubuntu on it, but when I boot from a USB, Ubuntu freezes at the initial Ubuntu boot up screen. This happens both when I "Try Ubuntu without installing" and "Try Ubuntu without installing (safe graphics)". This happens both with Ubuntu 18 and Ubuntu 20. I've been creating the bootable USB with Rufus 3.13 on Windows 10.

**Things I've Tried:**

- Disabling secure boot in the BIOS
- Tried both Ubuntu 18 and 20
- Reformatting the USB when creating the bootable USB
- Adding `nomodeset` to the boot options [Source](https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/)
- Adding `nouveau.noaccel=1` instead of `nomodeset` to the boot options
- Replacing `quiet splash` with `noapic noacpi nosplash irqpoll`
- Adding `acpi=off` to the boot options [Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861743/installation-of-ubuntu-16-04-from-a-usb-drive-freezes)

**Computer Specs:**

- Ryzen 7 1800X
- EVGA GTX 760 SC (temporary GPU)
- ASUS ROG Strix B450-F Gaming
- 32 GB Corsair Vengeance RAM (forget the speed)

I've pretty much tried everything I can think of at this point. Any suggestions would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update for anyone who stumbles upon this post: I have found the solution! I can't find where I read it, but apparently Ubuntu or Linux can have a voltage issue where it thinks (or actually doesn't) have enough power to function. Fixes for this include: unplugging your mouse; ensuring your mouse and keyboard aren't plugged in next to each other; or unplugging unused drives in your PC. Unplugging the mouse did it for me.